# Cannot view issue details after installing Redmine issue-id plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, bitnami, redmine-plugins

I have installed the ["issue-id" plugin](https://github.com/jett/issue-id) to Bitnami Redmine 3.1.1 running on Windows Server 2012R2.

Issue Ids have successfully changed for the new ones like "Project-1" on the issue list. (/projects/{Project Name}/issues)

However link URLs to issue details have been broken so I cannot view details for each issue. (I just get the "Internal error" screen as shown on the attached image.)

[image]

"production" log file says as follows:

> Started GET "/issues/Project-1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-20 11:00:07
>   Processing by IssuesController#show as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"id"=>"Project-1"}   Current user: jungal (id=1)   Rendered
>   issues/_action_menu.html.erb (34.0ms)   Rendered
>   plugins/redmine_contacts/app/views/deals_issues/_show.html.erb (2.0ms)
>   Rendered
>   plugins/redmine_contacts_helpdesk/app/views/issues/_ticket_data.html.erb
>   (0.0ms)   Rendered
>   plugins/redmine_products/app/views/products_issues/_products.html.erb
>   (32.0ms)   Rendered issues/show.html.erb within layouts/base
>   (1043.0ms) Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1632ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 319.5ms)
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"new",
>   :controller=>"journals", :id=>#} missing
>   required keys: [:id])
>
> ```
> 77: <% if @issue.description? %>
> 78: <div class="description">
> 79:   <div class="contextual">
> 80:   <%= link_to l(:button_quote), quoted_issue_path(@issue), :remote => true, :method => 'post', :class => 'icon icon-comment' if authorize_for('issues', 'edit') %>
> 81:   </div>
> 82: 
> 83:   <p><strong><%=l(:field_description)%></strong></p>   app/views/issues/show.html.erb:80:in
> ```
>
> `_app_views_issues_show_html_erb___574665212_71239980'
>
>   app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:118:in`block (2 levels) in show'
>   app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:115:in `show'
>
>   lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in`sudo_mode'

I have checked the actual issue id which is number and tried to set the URL like /issues/{number} but it was no use.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: As the text in the image says, "If you are the Redmine administratro, check your log files for details about the error." Those details may lead to an answer. Post them here if possible / necessary.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala I have added the "production" error message. The kind of error seems to be ActionView::Template::Error.

Answer (score 1):

That version of ISSUE-id plugin did not support Redmine 3.x. This was noted on [the plugin's page](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/issue_id) of the official Redmine website and on [the official plugin's webpage](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/project/redmine/issue-id). Installing such plugin versions on an unsupported Redmine version, unfortunately, means breaking the work of Redmine, like in this case (that's not the only issue you would experience under Redmine 3.x with that version of the plugin).

If the plugin does not support the version of Redmine, that you are using, the only solution is to attempt to find a fork of the plugin, that does support such version (or to ask author to prioritize adding such support). ISSUE-id had such [forks](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/projects/issue-id/wiki/Forks). Alternatively, you could check the development version in [SVN](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/projects/issue-id/repository), which, in theory, could include fixes for such issues already (not released yet). In any way, it's always a good idea to report such issues on [the official plugin's page](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/projects/issue-id/issues) (thus, you could get support from the plugin's community).

P.S. At the moment, the official plugin already supports Redmine 3.x, so this issue is fixed there.